# How to set the label Fonts as "Time New Roman" by drawparallels in python

Tags: python, matplotlib-basemap

I have draw a map with latitudes labelled but I want to set the fonts as "Times New Roman". How to make it possible?

m.drawparallels(parallels,labels=[1,0,0,0],fontsize=12)

Answer (score 62, accepted):

You need to set font family using `pyplot` of `matplotlib`.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
csfont = {'fontname':'Times New Roman'}
// write your code related to basemap here
plt.title('title',**csfont)
plt.show()
```

You can also use the following to change font globally.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.rcParams["font.family"] = "Times New Roman"
```

Comment: Thanks, I have successfully changed the global font as "Times New Roman". But if I want to only set the parallels or meridians label font, what is the keyword arg? The code are in the following.

from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
m = Basemap(projection='cyl',llcrnrlat=-90,urcrnrlat=90,\
            llcrnrlon=-180,urcrnrlon=180,resolution='c')
parallels = np.arange(-90.,91.,30.)
m.drawparallels(parallels,labels=[1,0,0,0],fontsize=8)

plt.show()

Comment: **kwargs = additional keyword arguments controlling text for labels that are passed on to the text method of the axes instance (see matplotlib.pyplot.text documentation). You can try using approach 1 to set font family for the drawparallels.

Comment: If you get an error saying `Font Family "Times New Roman" not found`, check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49884009/3337089)

Comment: Changing font style on Ubuntu is a nightmare. For the love of god, just switch to a Windows PC and do it. "Times New Roman" is a Microsoft font.