# how to change font on Times New Roman in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, fonts

I use matplotlib 3.2.2 with python 3.8 (PyCharm).

I would like to change font on Times New Roman like this:

```
from matplotlib.font_manager import FontProperties
font = FontProperties()
font.set_family('serif')
font.set_name('Times New Roman')
font.set_style('italic')
```

(from [matplotlib user's guide](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.2/tutorials/text/text_intro.html#sphx-glr-tutorials-text-text-intro-py))
But I got an error "**findfont: Font family ['Times'] not found. Falling back to DejaVu Sans.**"

I tried all of the solutions from another post ([Matplotlib cannot find basic fonts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42097053/matplotlib-cannot-find-basic-fonts#new-answer?newreg=8c1ece594e5c4507a8fc07cc30f95a6b)) and have no results.

Maybe something changed with time?
Thanks!

Comment: Have a look. https://stackoverflow.com/a/40734893/12965285

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately, it doesn't work too.